# I'm trying to write a discord bot in python but it says all code is wrong?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to write a discord bot in python but it says all code is wrong!

I have installed discord.py and I am using Python 3.5.

I do not understand why?

**My code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = ("NTU2NDMzMTIE3NDE4NzYz.D25qlg.O9DZ3Z826EYluNydApWZ3RBjj2Q")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

client.run(token)
```

**Error:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Kadir/PycharmProjects/untitled/Discord Bot Deniyoruz/Bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kadir\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kadir\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kadir\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kadir\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: it says syntax error in `compat.py`. Double check the python version that is required, or update the discord package maybe?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.2 and installed dicord.py today

Comment: Do not post your bot token publicly, even a modified/fake one. Consider regenerating it if it's the actual one.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. async (and currently latest) version of discord.py doesn't support 3.7 or newer, as `async` becomes a *reserved* keyword. Consider switching to rewrite version (which supports 3.7) or downgrading Python version to 3.6 or lower.